# Returning an array of common strings by comparing two arrays of strings in Dataweave 2.0

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have a dataweave script in which I'm using `keysOf` function to return the keys of the JSON payload from `inputPayload` as an array of strings in `keysList`. I want to compare the returned string with another array of strings `keySearch` and see the common strings in both arrays as a new array. Here I'm using `reduce` to apply reduction to find the common strings.

```
%dw 2.0
var inputPayload = {
  "name": "John",
  "age": 30,
  "hobbies": "reading",
  "skills": {
    "programming": "Java"
  }
}
var keysList = keysOf(inputPayload)
var keySearch = ["activities", "age"]
var matchingWords = keysList reduce (item, acc = []) -> if (keySearch contains item) acc + item else acc
output application/json
---
{
    keySearch: keySearch,
    keysList: keysList,
    difference: matchingWords
}
```

Here the `difference` field should print `[ "age" ]` but currently it is returning an empty string. If I pass the keysList manually, `difference` field will return an array as expected.
eg:  `var keysList = [ "name", "age", "married", "hobbies", "skills" ]`

The `keysList` variable has the same array of strings returned from the `keysOf` function. Could anyone help in finding why I'm not able to get the difference when using reduce function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script has some issues. Probably the main problem is that `keysOf()` returns an array of `Key`s rather than strings. That could make comparisons to String fail unless you convert the type. Instead it is simpler to use `namesOf()` which returns an array of strings.

The second point is not really a an issue, but using reduce() in this manner is not very intuitive and I would say not very suited to to a functional language like DataWeave. It is more logical to me to think that you want to remove the elements that are not in both lists. That is a filtering operation. You can just use `filter()` on the array for that. Note that while I said 'remove' DataWeave will always return a new array with the elements removed.

```js
%dw 2.0
var inputPayload = {
  "name": "John",
  "age": 30,
  "hobbies": "reading",
  "skills": {
    "programming": "Java"
  }
}
var keysList = namesOf(inputPayload)
var keySearch = ["activities", "age"]
output application/json
---
{
    keySearch: keySearch,
    keysList: keysList,
    keysMatching: keysList filter (keySearch contains $) 
}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "keySearch": [
    "activities",
    "age"
  ],
  "keysList": [
    "name",
    "age",
    "hobbies",
    "skills"
  ],
  "keysMatching": [
    "age"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Key needs to be type casted to String. Change the below line to add `item as String` instead of `item`

```
var matchingWords = keysList reduce (item, acc = []) -> if (keySearch contains (item as String)) acc + item else acc
```

Comment: thanks @sudhish_s for the answer. This directly addresses the issue!